# Grunt Jasmine configuration

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

In the following Grunt configuration for Jasmine, what is the `pivotal` property for?

```
// Example configuration
grunt.initConfig({
  jasmine: {
    pivotal: {
      src: 'src/**/*.js',
      options: {
        specs: 'spec/*Spec.js',
        helpers: 'spec/*Helper.js'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Is it for "namespacing" your tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pivotal` is a target. Right now you have a task `jasmine` with a single target `pivotal`.

If you had multiple targets you could selectively run just the one task with `grunt jasmine:pivotal`.

If you have multiple targets and use `grunt jasmine` it will run the jasmine task for all of the defined targets.

This is further documented at: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets